# what approve and allowance methods are really doing in ERC20 Standard?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

The problem is what `allowance` and `approve` are really doing?

And what is `_spender` and what is it doing?

Is there anybody who can explain it to me?

```
contract Token {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 value) returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 value) returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> what allowance and approve are doing really?

Let's assume we have user **A** and user **B**. **A** has 1000 tokens and want to give permission to **B** to spend 100 of them.

- **A** will call `approve(address(B), 100, {"from": address(A)})`
- **B** will check how many tokens **A** gave him permission to use by calling: `allowance(address(A), address(B))`
- **B** will send to his account these tokens by calling:                              `transferFrom(address(A), address(B), 100, {"from": address(B)})`

Comment: In transferFrom, can B send this money to someone else like C?

Comment: Yes, B can send token to C in that case. @EresDev

Answer (score 10):

- `Allowance` means that we can grant approval to another contract or address to be able to transfer our ERC20 tokens. And this requirement is common in distributed applications, such as escrows, games, auctions, etc. Hence, we need a way to approve other addresses to spend our tokens. Let's say you have `tether` contract and you want a DEX(Decentralized Exchange) or any other entity transfer coins from the `tether` contract. So you keep track of which entity how much can transfer from tether contract in a mapping.

  ```
   // my address is allowing your address for this much token
   mapping(address=>mapping(address=>uint)) public allowance;
  ```
- In the ERC20 standard, we have a global variable `allowed` in which we keep the mapping from an "owner's address" to an "approved spender’s" address and then to the amount of tokens. Calling `approve()` function can add an approval to its desired `_spender` and `_value`. The amount of token is not checked here and it will be checked in transfer().
- Once the approval is granted, the "approved spender" can use `transferFrom()` to transfer tokens. `_from` is the owner address and `_to` is the receiver’s address and `_value` is the required number of tokens to be sent. First, we check if the owner actually possesses the required number of tokens.

Let's say you want to deposit some ether to a DEFI platform. Interacting with a DEFI platform is actually interacting with the smart contract of that platform. Before you deposit money, you first `approve` the transaction. You are telling that this contract address can take some money from my account. Then you call the `deposit` function of DEFI smart contract and deposit the money. This how transfer occurs in order:

1- Inside Defi, defi contract has `deposit` to get coin from `tether`

```
function depositTokens(uint _amount) public{
  require(_amount>0,'amount cannot be zero');
  // transfer tether to this contract address for staking
  tether.transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this), _amount);
 // update the state inside Defi, like staked tokens, amount etc
}
```

2- Inside `tether` we have `transferFrom`

```
mapping(address=>mapping(address=>uint)) public allowance;

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
        // check the allowance
        require(_value <=allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        balanceOf[_to]+=_value;
        balanceOf[_from]-=_value;
        allowance[_from][msg.sender]-=_value;
        emit Transfer(_from,_to,_value);
        return true;
    }
```

The first requirement is checking the allowance. `mapping(address=>mapping(address=>uint)) public allowance`. So actually before calling this, `tether` contract has to update its `allowance` mapping so this `transferFrom` will run smoothly

3- Update the allowance with `approve`:

```
function approve(address _spender, uint _value)public returns (bool success){
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender]=_value;
        // This event must trigger when a successful call is made to the approve function.
        emit Approval(msg.sender,_spender,_value);
        return true;
    }
```