# Is approve needed before calling transferFrom?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

if my farm contract has a staking function, do I need to call approve before calling transferFrom?

Sample function:

```
StakeToken stakingToken;
...
function depositTokens(uint256 amount) public {
    require(amount > 0, "Must be more than 0");
    //Do I need to call stakingToken.approve(...) here?
    stakingToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
```

Is this needed because the farm contract must be approved to make the transfer on the msg.sender's behalf?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664570/what-approve-and-allowance-methods-are-really-doing-in-erc20-standard/68820999#68820999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `approve()` is needed, but you cannot call it from within your contract. The user needs to call it directly from their address.

So transfering tokens from the user effectively requires two transactions. First one to `token.approve()` and the second to `yourContract.depositTokens()`.

**Reasoning**: The token contract approves spending `msg.sender`'s tokens to the address specified in the `approve()` function first argument. With that said, when you invoke `token.approve()` from your contract, the `msg.sender` within the `approve()` function is your contract - not the user. So in that case, you would be approving tokens to be spent from your contract to whichever address is passed as the argument.